# "Could not find or load main class" while trying to use JavaFX in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

java version 1.8.0_221
eclipse version 2019-06 (4.12.0)
I'm trying to make a basic JavaFX program. I've imported jfxrt external jar into the libraries tab under module build path.

I've been getting this error "Error: Could not find or load main class firstFX.eighthTry
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application"

The only advice I've found around the web tells me to get rid of any external jars, but I need jfxswt in order to use JavaFX. I've also tried to use Project > Clean, but that hasn't done anything either.

I'm at a loss, is there anything I can do to fix this? Code is below

```
package firstFX;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class eighthTry extends Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage arg0){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        arg0.setTitle("Hello World!");

        final Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Click Me!");

        final StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        arg0.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        arg0.show();

    }

}
```

Edit:
I've done a clean install of Eclipse (now 2019-09) and also installed e(fx)clipse via Help>Install new software then installing both things from http://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/updates-released/3.3.0/site. I followed [this tutorial](https://o7planning.org/en/10623/javafx-tutorial-for-beginners).

For my code I added the JavaFX SDK under Properties> Java Build Path > Libraries>Module Path. I then put it at the top of the Order and Export tab.

Unfortunately, this hasn't changed anything. I still get the same error as I did above.

Additionally, I was mistaken about the name of the external jar I needed. I have since replaced the jfxswt.jar with jfxrt.jar. However, this has not fixed the error.

Comment: clean the project and refresh in eclipse, try it may work.

Comment: it should actually work without `jfxswt.jar` - the missing class should be in `jfxrt.jar` which comes with JDK8/JRE8 (in `ext` directory) - make sure the JRE System Library for JavaSE **1.8** is being included in your project (JavaFX is part of Java 8, but NOT part of later versions of Java)

Comment: I have no 2019-06 here, but worked fine with 2019-03 and 2019-09 - just had to change project to include JRE8 (Java Build Path - Libraries - JRE System Library - Execution Environment: 8 {and java JDK8 configured} or Alternate JRE: 8)

Comment: _under module build path_ sounds fishy: java8 has no modules

Answer (score -1):

Not sure how it looks but your class is missing package firstFX; is it in a folder called firstFX... ?