# Using JavaFX13 with Java 13/8 and have JNI error?

Tags: java, javafx

Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again.

Eclipse states: test has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 56.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0.

I had the problem referenced at this question: ["Could not find or load main class" while trying to use JavaFX in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58648826/could-not-find-or-load-main-class-while-trying-to-use-javafx-in-eclipse?answertab=active#tab-top) When using JDK13 and JavaFX13.  All solutions pointed to downgrading to Java 8.

I installed Java 8, updated the build path, and it built fine.  But now I get the error   I am using Eclipse 2019-06 (4.12.0), JavaFX13, and JDK 1.8.0_231.

I researched the answer but the two questions that come didn't help.  One was for an IntellJ solution and the other had a package I am unfamiliar with, and the error had to do with that package.

I simply don't know how to correct the build path or dependencies to fix this issue. It appears I need a lower version of the JVM, but cannot seem to locate it.  Am I right, or can you please help?

Comment: ["JavaFX 13 requires JDK 11 or later"](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/doc-files/release-notes-13.md)

Comment: JNI error means,  that JavaFX likely is in need of accessing a native function internally which however does not exist for this JDK version.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have dropped back to JDK 8 and the built in JavaFX.  Despite my best efforts, I cannot get JDK13 and JavaFX 13 to work without receiving the error "Could not find or load main class" (see link in post).  Since there is no solution to that problem yet that works for me, I can bypass my error on this request all together and just use much older packages.

Comment: Or you could read and follow the detailled instructions here https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/